# Efectos al mostrar *ngIf

Tags: angular

me gustaría saber como puedo hacer para que al mostrar un div con *ngIf haga algún tipo de efecto como el transition en CSS por ejemplo el ngIf que estoy haciendo es ocultar un div

```
<span class="close-creategroups" (click)="closeTab()"><i class="fas fa-times-circle"></i></span>



closeTab() {
    this.filterIdentificador = "";
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Para conseguir este efecto con el *ngIf debes utilizar angular animations (que permiten definir animaciones para enter/leave de los elementos):

```js
import { trigger, style, animate, transition } from '@angular/animations';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  animations: [
    trigger(
      'enterAnimation', [
        transition(':enter', [
          style({transform: 'translateX(100%)', opacity: 0}),
          animate('500ms', style({transform: 'translateX(0)', opacity: 1}))
        ]),
        transition(':leave', [
          style({transform: 'translateX(0)', opacity: 1}),
          animate('500ms', style({transform: 'translateX(100%)', opacity: 0}))
        ])
      ]
    )
  ],
  template: `
    <button (click)="show = !show">toggle show ({{show}})</button>

    <div *ngIf="show" [@enterAnimation]>xxx</div>
  `
})
export class App {
  show:boolean = false;
}
```